# Google Analytics Admin API：GA4データ抽出時のデータストリームによるフィルタリングについて

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics

GA4のアナリティクスデータ取得を行なう際に、データストリームのストリームIDによるフィルタリングを行ないたいのですが、可能でしょうか？

現在まで実施し、成功しているのは以下の通りです。

[1] OAuth2認証を経由してのリフレッシュトークンの取得
[2] Admin APIによるプロパティリストの取得
[3] Admin APIによるプロパティごとのデータストリームの取得
[4] [2]のプロパティIDを使用し、Analytics Data API (GA4)を利用してのデータ取得

[4]において、dimensionFilterを使用して、オーガニックのみに限定＋コンバージョンイベントのEventNameを指定してのアナリティクスデータ取得も問題なく出来ております。

やろうとしているのは、データ取得の際に[3]で取得したデータストリームのストリームIDを指定して、特定のデータストリームに限定してのデータ抽出は出来ないのか？ということです。

dimensionFilterでストリームIDを指定できればと考えたものの、それらしき方法が見つからず苦慮しております。
あるいは、そもそもデータストリームを限定してアナリティクスデータを取得するということ自体が不可能ということかとも思ったのですが、そちらも明確な資料を見つけられずにおります。

関連するドキュメントだけでも分かれば幸いですので、よろしくお願いいたします。